# how to define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-settings

I am trying to `chainedForeignKey` using https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html and I got following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
USE_DJANGO_JQUERY, but settings are not configured. You must either
define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

# Create your models here.
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Store(models.Model):
    store = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = ChainedForeignKey(Area, chained_field="city", chained_model_field="city")
```

Comment: Did you try to set the environment variables?

Comment: yes i tried the way suggested at https://alicecampkin.medium.com/how-to-set-up-environment-variables-in-django-f3c4db78c55f